# Current texting message is lost in JSQMessagesViewController with swift3

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift3, message

I used JSQMessagesViewController in my project.
My current texting message is  automatic disappear(lost) when new message is received. I always need to text again and again. How to solve this problem?. Please, help me anyone have this experience.

Comment: share some of your code where you save text into array and reply. I think your array is replaced with new array when you receive new message

Comment: Will you share your demo ?

Comment: How can I check without Running it that what's going on in the messaging ? If you dont mind to share it with me